# X11 Display Environment error (Trying to run Octave)

Tags: macos, octave

I'm relatively new to Mac (just got it today), but I'm trying to get Octave situated on this computer per advice from a friend of one of the gnu-octave compiler developers that I talked to last night.

I've gone through and I've installed everything including Xquartz and Octave and I've been utilizing this wiki to guide me through it, yet I'm still getting an error

"X11 DISPLAY environment variable not set"

I thought xquartz fulfilled this X11 requirement, but I'm really new to to this, so I could very well be wrong.

My goal: to have a fully functional Octave :)

Best regards,

Brooks

Comment: Sorry here is the wiki being used: http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X

Comment: that wiki page has instructions to install Octave through 4 different methods. You should specify which one you're trying, and you really should be trying one of the package managers.